# Django 1.11 upgrade - object has no attribute 'password'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I've been running fine on Django 1.7.  I'm trying to upgrade to 1.11.

I'm getting the following error on 1.11 and I can't seem to find the problem.

Here's the code in question:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=True, db_index=True)
    pet_shop_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    django_user = models.OneToOneField(User, to_field='username', parent_link=True, null=True,
                                       db_column="django_username", default=None, db_index=True, db_constraint=False)
```

The problem is when I call:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id='x')  # pulls a valid profile
print profile.django_user
```

I get this error:

Exception Value:

```
'Profile' object has no attribute 'password'

Exception Location:     /Users/../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in <dictcomp>, line 291
```

Comment: Your`django_user` field has `parent_link=True`.
Is `Profile` model supposed to inherit from `User` ?

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't notice that.  Taking it out seems to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @adrien mentioned in the comment, that was the issue.  I had to remove the parent_link=True in the one to one field to User.